# Find the smallest number such that

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

If you move the last digit of a number to the front, then it becomes nine times larger. Find the smallest such number.

So what I've tried is :

Let $N = x_nx_{n-1}...x_1x_0$

$\implies 9(x_nx_{n-1}...x_1x_0) = x_0x_n...x_1$

Let $y = x_nx_{n-1}...x_1$. Then $N = 10y + x_0$. Let $N'= 10^{n}x_0 + y$

$9N = N'\\
9(10y + x_0) = 10^{n}x_0 + y\\
89y = x_0(10^{n}-9)$

I am lost after this.I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $N'= 10^{n}x_0 + y$?

Comment: Ah, you're right

Comment: Note that $89$ is prime, so $x_0\nmid 89$ and $10^n-9\equiv 0\pmod{89}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $89$ is prime, and $1\leq x_0\leq9$, we know that $89\mid10^n-9$, that is $$10^n\equiv9\text{ mod }89.$$  Note that $9\cdot10\equiv 1 \text{ mod }89$, so  $$10^n\equiv1\text{ mod }89\iff9\cdot10^n\equiv9\text{ mod }89\iff10^{n-1}\equiv9\text{ mod }89$$

By Fermat's little theorem, $10^{88}\equiv1\text{ mod }89$ and any $k$ such that $10^k\equiv1\text{ mod }89$ must be a divsior of $88$.  We find by trial that the smallest divisor that works is $k=44$ so the smallest possible value of $n$ is $n=43$.

Since $9N=N'$ and $N$ and $N'$ have the same number of digits, it must be the case that $x_0=9$.  Putting this together, the smallest possible value of $y$ is $$y=\frac{9\left(10^{43}-9\right)}{89},$$ and then $$N=10y+9.$$

This gives $$\begin{align}N&=10112359550561797752808988764044943820224719,\\N'=9N&=91011235955056179775280898876404494382022471\end{align}$$

Comment: Very nice answer! I tried working back the next digit from the 1s and gave up at around the 20th digit :)

Comment: Gor!  I can't tell you how *long* I struggled trying to solve $10^k \equiv 9\pmod {89}$ knowing that $10^{44}\equiv 1$.  I can't believe I didn't try $10^{k+1} \equiv 90\equiv 1\equiv 10^{44}$...... *sheeesh*......

Comment: Ah thanks for the wonderful solution!